# Hadoop DistributedCache classpath

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a Hadoop 0.20.2 cluster.

I'm thinking of using [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) to distribute the job code to all the nodes. I can't understand the difference between `addFileToClassPath()` and `addArchiveToClassPath()`. Logically, it would seem that the former is for single class files, and the latter is for jars. But right in the javadocs, they have this example code:

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/myapp/mylib.jar"), job);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? When you submit the job with `hadoop jar ...` it ships the `.jar` file everywhere automatically.

Comment: @orangeoctopus - That would be horribly inefficient in our case. I have dependencies on a lot of libraries, so this jar would be very big. I don't want to send the whole thing over the network, to every slave node, every time I start a job.

Comment: The distributed cache is going to do that, too. It's not permanently going to push that file out, it is a cache so it'll get flushed over time. Typically people do this by installing the libraries on all their nodes and adding them to the classpath, without the help of the Hadoop API. In production people use something like Puppet for this purpose.

Comment: Seems to be still active bug associated with this.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-752

Answer (score 2):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522242/adding-jar-via-distributed-cache-hadoop) could be helpful

as one of the users mentioned in the comment section there is a bug associated with `addArchiveToClassPath()` . the best way to learn and solve the problem is by updating your Hadoop to 1.0.0

[From the apache website:](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/index-all.html)

`addArchiveToClassPath` Add an archive path to the current set of classpath entries. It adds the archive to cache as well. Archive files **will be unpacked** and added to the classpath when being distributed.

`addFileToClassPath` Add an file path to the current set of classpath entries It adds the file to cache as well. Files added with this method **will not be unpacked** while being added to the classpath. To add archives to classpath, use the addArchiveToClassPath(Path) method instead.

I have realized that the Hadoop document is written by somebody who does not know english grammer very well. I see why you are frustrated.

Comment: It's relevant, I don't know that it explains why the "File" and "Archive" versions are different.

Comment: @SeanOwen edited the question for more explanation. Thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Hadoop isn't always feasible - as someone suggested, in this case it makes sense to just package this jar with the jar for the MR job, even a large JAR is unlikely to impact performance significantly.

Also, if the jar contains the code for the job you are submitting, there is no need to add it to the DistributedCache, submitting a job to hadoop means that the Hadoop job runner will take care of distributing your jar to all the nodes that are running mappers or reducers. Adding files to the DistributedCache is only necessary if you want some external data to accompany your job.

Comment: Same, this is all correct, but didn't get at the "File" vs "Archive" method difference that I was originally interested in too.

Answer (score 0):

I found some additional info later, and looked at the source, to discover that the "File" method copies one local file to one HDFS file, but the "Archive" version unpacks a compressed local archive to HDFS. That is the difference.

On a related note, to answer the "why bother?" comments -- I have a relatively large JAR file (20MB) and a job that will run about 20 M/R jobs in succession using the same code. It's iterative. This save a non-trivial amount of data transfer to upload the code once.