# Adding jar via distributed cache hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am adding a .jar file to the class path using Disributed Cache:

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("binary/tools.jar"), job.getConfiguration());
```

I am not sure whether addFileToClassPath() is the correct API to be used for adding .jar files to the class path. When I try to retrieve the class path from the mapper, I could not see the added jar. The classpath contains the working directory for the job (jobcache dir), but that does not include the jar distributed through Distributed Cache.

```
Properties prop = System.getProperties();
System.out.println("The classpath is: " + prop.getProperty("java.class.path", null));
```

I tried addArchiveToClassPath() too.. It did no work..

Am I missing something ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

The problem was was with the path. `addFileToClassPath()` or `addArchiveToClassPath()` takes only absolute path as input. binary/tools.jar is relative and hence did not work. I need to specify the path as `/user/<username>/binary/tools.jar..`  Now it works fine. Even `hdfs://<hostname>:port/user/..` fails.

Thank you all..

Comment: Which means I have to parse the URI and strip out the `(hdfs://hostname:port|file:)` myself. blech. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Is the jar you are adding to the classpath on the local file system, or in HDFS?

DistributedCache expects the path you name to be in HDFS