# Distributed Cache Jar in classpath but getting ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, classpath, distributed-cache

Using HBaseTestingUtility I would start a minicluster.

```
testUtil = new HBaseTestingUtility(configuration);
testUtil.startMiniCluster();
```

and provide my jar to place in DistributedCache's classpath

```
final String aJarResourcePath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
            .getResource("abc/a-1.0.jar").getPath();
    final FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);
    final Path pathToArtifacts = new Path("/Runtime/a-artifacts");
        fs.mkdirs(pathToArtifacts);
    fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path(aJarResourcePath), pathToArtifacts));

DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(disqualified, configuration);
```

On my MapFn I am using the jar a-1.0.jar. I am able to see the jar in the MapFn

```
final Path[] fus = DistributedCache.getFileClassPaths(config);
```

So I am thinking the jar is in classpath and points to HDFS location but I get classnotfoundexception trying to create an object. I am not sure whats going on please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this the cause of your problem, but the 2 argument overload of `addFileToClasspath` is [deprecated](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html#addFileToClassPath%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29) in Hadoop 1.2.1.  (Indeed in Hadoop 2.7.2, it appears that the `DistributedCache` class is [deprecated](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) in its entirety!)  The javadocs don't say *why* the method has been deprecated, so it is hard to know if this could be the problem.

**UPDATE**

A bit more research suggests that your problem may actually be that the JAR file is [not being expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15724536/139985).  Try using `addArchiveToClasspath` instead.